# How to create a VPN only accessible website hosted in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

So I have my website hosted in aws and is publicly available through the internet. However, I only want users access to the website through a connection via a VPN only. I already have a OpenVPN server setup in the aws. How do I now make my website acessible through that VPN connection only?

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you the steps involved.

#### Step 1 - create private subnets

A private subnet is just a normal subnet with no routes to the internet. create more than one private subnets, better to have one per availability zone. your application will be secure in the private subnets since it is not reachable from the internet.

#### Step 2 - deploy your application.

you should configure and deploy your application to use private subnets. if you have a load balancer, configure and redeploy the load balancer to be internal.

#### Step -3 VPN server

you need to install the OpenVPN server on an instance running on the public subnet.

#### Step 4 - Securing your application

Adjust your application or instance security groups to allow traffic only from the VPN server.

hope this helps.

Comment: you haven't answered the question. The setp 4  is the actual question and you didn't explain how to set it up. how to "adjust" the application?

Answer (score 0):

1. Move your website to a private subnet.
2. Configure VPN connection using any of the [these ways](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpn-connections.html).

Comment: So I have my ec2 instance in a vpc/subnet. I am going through the Client VPN method. My question is do I use the same subnet for the client vpn as my ec2 or should it be in a different subnet?
I am just starting to learn and could really use a good tutorial if there is any in doing this process. Thanks.

Comment: VPN connection is P2P. In your case one point is outside of your network and another point is inside subnet with AWS resource. AWS tutorials are step by step. It's much faster to read and try them first.